# RHEL 6 VM not booting Unexpected inconsistency

Tags: virtual-machine, redhat-enterprise-linux

I have  a daily backup that starts around 5pm, and i think yesterday it kicked while my VM was powered on which corrupted or something to my VM

[image: Error on boot]

Comment: Why is your answer to your question, in the question itself, if you have already self-answered the question?

Answer (score 0):

I typed my password at the above prompt and hit enter

Now i am trying fsck hit enter

and it's asking to fix thing with (y) and i am just hitting enter

[image]

Rebooting

Reboot sequence threw lot of error saying cannot remove read only

This Fixed it

But i remember this one last time where this issue came back